AutomaticNumbering does not recognize my privately created style
Automatic Numbering does not recognize my privately created style:
Cell[StyleData["Exercise", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
 MenuSortingValue->10000]

also tried the following modification:
Cell[StyleData["Exercise", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
CounterIncrements->"Exercise",
 MenuSortingValue->10000]

In either case, invoking Insert>Automatic Numbering (and selecting style Exercise) produces 0

Did you insert any "Exercise" cells anywhere? The Insert | Automatic Numbering menu item will insert the number of "Exercise" cells present before the insertion point, and if there are no "Exercise" cells, the result will be 0.

Please list steps required to reproduce the issue.
